# how to auto fille conatct form 7 when user is logined

Tags: customization, javascript, plugin-contact-form-7, autocomplete

I want to auto fill some details in contact 7 form , when user is logined and how to pass php value to js.

**in function.php**

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

 echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $custemail = $current_user->user_email;

function get_user_fild_details(){

?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        function codeAddress() {
            var phoneMaddy = '<?php echo $custemail; ?>';
            alert('ok');
document.getElementById('nameMaddyC').value=phoneMaddy; 

        }

        window.onload = codeAddress;
        </script>

<?php
}    
add_action("wp_head", "get_user_fild_details");
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do with jquery like:

```
 <?php global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
  echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
  echo 'User level: ' . $current_user->user_level . "\n";
  echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
  echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
  echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
  echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
  ?>
```

first get all login user data and then get contact form field id like #unsemae

```
$("#unsemae").val("<?php echo $current_user->user_login ;?>");
```

Thnk you

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the mistake i am doing.

```
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {


    function get_user_fild_details(){
**I just moved in to this function . I think its scope issue. Now its working fine** 
     echo 'Welcome, registered user!'; 
         $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $custemail = $current_user->user_email;
    ?>

     <script type="text/javascript">
            function codeAddress() {
                var phoneMaddy = '<?php echo $custemail; ?>';
                alert('ok');
    document.getElementById('nameMaddyC').value=phoneMaddy; 

            }

            window.onload = codeAddress;
            </script>

    <?php
    }    
    add_action("wp_head", "get_user_fild_details");
     }
```